# Problems with Destroying Instantiated Gameobject in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I instantiated `Gameobject`,and now I want to destroy it,but for some unknown reason i cant find way to do that.When I check if position of the object is smaller than some number, even it is smaller it wont execute code in if statement: Below is the code, so if someone have an idea how to destroy these instantiated objects:

```cs
[SerializeField]
GameObject Jabuka;
[SerializeField]
GameObject kruska;
[SerializeField]
GameObject brisacDonji;
[SerializeField]
GameObject brisacGornji;

public float MoveSpeed = 3f;

public GameObject spawnerOdozgo;
public GameObject spawnerOdozdo;

GameObject UIjabuka;
GameObject UIkruska;

Rigidbody2D jabukaRig;
Rigidbody2D kruskaRig;

float minx = -2f;
float maxx = 2f;

float vrijemeSpawna = 2f;
float nextSpawn = 0f;

int staSpawnati;
int SpawnGoreILidole;

float positionPos;
public float veclocityI;

private Vector2 screenBounds;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    veclocityI = Random.Range(2, 6);
    positionPos = Random.Range(minx, maxx);

    SpawnGoreILidole = Random.Range(1, 3);
    switch (SpawnGoreILidole)
    {
        case 1:
            spawnOdozgo();
            break;
        case 2:
            spawnOdozdo();
            break;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
}

public void spawnOdozgo()
{
    if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
    {
        staSpawnati = Random.Range(1, 3);
        Debug.Log("sta" + staSpawnati);

        switch (staSpawnati)
        {
            case 1:
                UIjabuka = Instantiate(Jabuka, new Vector3(positionPos, spawnerOdozgo.transform.position.y, 1), transform.rotation);
                jabukaRig = UIjabuka.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                jabukaRig.velocity = new Vector2(0, -veclocityI);
                if (UIjabuka.transform.position.y < brisacDonji.transform.position.y)
                {
                    Destroy(UIjabuka);
                    Debug.Log("unisteno je");
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                UIkruska = Instantiate(kruska, new Vector3(positionPos, spawnerOdozgo.transform.position.y, 1), transform.rotation);
                kruskaRig = UIkruska.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                kruskaRig.velocity = new Vector2(0, -veclocityI);
                break;
        }

        nextSpawn = Time.time + vrijemeSpawna;
    }
}

public void spawnOdozdo()
{
    if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
    {
        staSpawnati = Random.Range(1, 3);
        Debug.Log("sta" + staSpawnati);

        switch (staSpawnati)
        {
            case 1:
                UIjabuka = Instantiate(Jabuka, new Vector3(Random.Range(minx, maxx), spawnerOdozdo.transform.position.y, 1), transform.rotation);
                jabukaRig = UIjabuka.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                jabukaRig.velocity = new Vector2(0, veclocityI);

                break;
            case 2:
                UIkruska = Instantiate(kruska, new Vector3(Random.Range(minx, maxx), spawnerOdozdo.transform.position.y, 1), transform.rotation);
                kruskaRig = UIkruska.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                kruskaRig.velocity = new Vector2(0, veclocityI);
                break;
        }

        nextSpawn = Time.time + vrijemeSpawna;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough time to look at your entire code. But if your switch statement case is not 1 then your if statament wil never execute. you need to make sure your variable: `staSpawnati` is set to 1 if you want the object to be destroyed.

Comment: position of UI jabuke is f.e -20 and position of brisacDonji is -10,evene the position is lower the code of if statement wont execute.

Comment: if your staSpawnati is not 1 your switch statement wont execute your if statement

Answer (score 0):

From the code posted above, you need to satisfy 3 conditions to reach the Destroy function.

1. **SpawnGoreILidole must be 1** to satisfy the first switch case and enter the spawnOdozgo()
2. **staSpawnati must be 1** to satisfy the second switch case and enter the code section where the Destroy is.
3. **UIjabuka.transform.position.y must be less than brisacDonji.transform.position.y** and then the Destroy will be executed over the UIjabuka gameobject.

From my point of view the code makes no sense at all because you will be destroying the GameObject that you created 4 lines above. But these are the conditions needed for the Destroy to be executed.